# Receiving Non-Null Messages when receiving from empty Azure ServiceBus Queue using Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

When retrieving messages from an SB Queue using the Java SDK (0.4.1), a non-null `ReceiveQueueMessageResult` is returned even if the Queue in question is empty. Calling `getValue()` on that result returns a non-null `BrokeredMessage`. How am I supposed to tell that I’ve called receive on an empty Queue? Obviously querying size is not an option in a distributed, concurrent system.

I'm using `ReceiveAndDelete` Mode and the Queue is newly created so I KNOW it's empty.

According to docs, the underlying call to the API should return a StatusCode of 204. I can not find any way to access that Code in the returned Result or Message.

Comment: I've found the response header buried the MessageHeaders (responses) in an anonymous inner class of type DelegateHttpsURLConnection in the BrokeredMessage. Sure enough there's a 204 in there. No way to get to it (that I can find) via the interface on BrokeredMessage.

Answer (score 1):

We have recorded this issue, we are working on a fix now. By the way, Windows Azure SDK for Java is open source, you can even submit your own fix if you are willing to giveup the copyright to MSFT. The source code can be found https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java

Comment: Have already forked the project.
A couple of comments about a solution.
1) A call to an empty queue, should not, IMO, cause a ServiceException. 200 series status codes indicates a successful/correct invocation. The 204 code returned indicates the queue was empty, this is not an Exceptional or Error condition.
2) The current implementation returns an empty BrokeredMessage. A content-length of 0 should not indicate that the Queue is empty. It's common practice in messaging systems to create valid messages that have no body, but convey their intent via headers/properties.

Comment: Have implemeted a fix and submitted a pull request under github id: billAtPros.